# Silverlight element to element binding in generic.xaml

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, custom-controls

Is there a way to have element to element binding in Silverlight templated controls?

Example: I have two custom controls, `SomeControl` and `CustomSlider`. `SomeControl` has a dependency property called `someValue`. I want to bind the value of `CustomSlider` to this property, so my generic.xaml file looks like this:

> ```
> <Style TargetType="local:SomeControl">
>     <Setter Property="Template">
>         <Setter.Value>
>             <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SomeControl">
>                 <...>
>             </ControlTemplate>
>         </Setter.Value>
>     </Setter>
> </Style>
> ```

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomSlider">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomSlider">
                <Slider Value="{Binding someValue, ElementName=local:SomeControl}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and this is my dependency property:

> ```
>   public int someValue, 
>     {
>         get { return (int)GetValue(someValueProperty); }
>         set { SetValue(someValueProperty, value); }
>     }
>     public static readonly DependencyProperty (someValueProperty) =
>         DependencyProperty.Register(someValue); typeof(int), typeof(SomeControl,
>           new PropertyMetadata(0));
> ```

This throws an "BindingExpression_CannotFindElementName" exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it like this. A binding through `ElementName` should be used to specific element instance, not style. You can create other dependency property, say `SliderValue` in your `CustomSlider`control and bind to it.

```
<local:SomeControl x:Name="SomeControl"/>
<local:CustomSlider SliderValue="{Binding someValue, ElementName=SomeControl}"/>
```

And change your Slider `Value` from template when your `SliderValue` property changes;